# ANSI color codes in compiled CLI

Tags: terminal, elixir, ansi-escape

I'm building a CLI utility in Elixir, and am putting a little extra effort into the UX because it will probably see a lot of reuse.

When I include lines like `IO.puts(IO.ANSI.format([:yellow,"some output"]))` and run the app by using `iex -S mix` and invoking the entry point directly, everything works as expected.

However, when I build the app using `mix escript.build` and then invoke it with `./{the_app_name}`, the app runs just fine, but the ANSI codes are apparently stripped, since the colors are all gone.

Obviously not an absolutely critical issue, but it would go a long way to enhancing the usability of the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it can be seen from the [code](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.12.3/lib/elixir/lib/io/ansi.ex#L67), [`IO.ANSI.enabled?/0`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/IO.ANSI.html#enabled?/0) is `false` by default. I believe (I have not tested it though,) that explicitly enabling it would do a trick.

```elixir
Application.put_env(:elixir, :ansi_enabled, true)

[:yellow, "some output"]
|> IO.ANSI.format()
|> IO.puts()
```

Comment: That's brilliant @aleksei! Works perfectly. (Also, thank you for subtly and nonjudgementally 'correcting' my code to piped style. I work largely without colleagues in Elixir, so seeing more idiomatic code from someone with more experience in the language is also a great help)

Comment: (And also for the reminder that Elixir core source code can be explored and is mostly quite clear and comprehensible. My Java + .NET experience constantly blinds me to that)

Comment: Always welcome!

Answer (score 0):

This also works.

While formatting the text, you can simply pass the boolean `true`.

```
IO.ANSI.format([:green, "Greenery Text"], true)
```